# Clojure - find largest of list without using max

Tags: clojure

i'm trying to write a simple Clojure program to find the maximum element of a list. This is the code I wrote so far:

```clj
(ns iotest.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn getLargest [L]
  "Get the largest element of a given list L"
  (cond
   (empty? L) nil
   (empty? (rest L)) (first L)
    ((> (first L) (getLargest (rest L)))) (first L)
    :else (getLargest (rest L))))

(defn -main []
  (let
    [L (4 5 10 1)
     largest (getLargest L)]
    (println "Largest element of" L "is" largest)))
```

The problem is, I get the following error(i'm using leiningen):

```
class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**I know about the `max` function, but I want to implement it by myself for learning purposes.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
 (let [L (4 5 10 1) ... )
```

is missing [`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote)- or you can use vector instead:

```
(4 5 10 1)
error

'(4 5 10 1)
=> (4 5 10 1)

[4 5 10 1]
=> [4 5 10 1]
```

There is also error with `((> (first L) (getLargest (rest L)))) (first L)` (*class java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn*, you have additional pair of parentheses here) and style error with `getLargest`- Clojure uses kebab-case, so correct name is `get-largest`.

For correct result check [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce). [`Min`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/min) and [`max`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max) don't work for empty lists, so you have to be careful about that:

```
(defn get-largest [lst]
  (if (empty? lst) 
    :none
    (reduce (fn [acc element] 
              (if (> element acc) element acc))
            (first lst)
            (rest lst))))

(let [lst [4 5 10 1]
      largest (get-largest lst)]
  (println "Largest element of" lst "is" largest))

Largest element of [4 5 10 1] is 10
=> nil

(let [lst []
      largest (get-largest lst)]
  (println "Largest element of" lst "is" largest))

Largest element of [] is :none
=> nil
```

**EDIT:** This is a little bit better:

```
(defn get-largest [lst]
  (when (seq lst)
    (reduce #(if (> %2 %1) %2 %1)
            (first lst)
            (rest lst))))

(let [lst [4 5 10 1]]
  (if-let [largest (get-largest lst)]
    (println "Largest element of" lst "is" largest)
    (println "Sequence is empty")))

Largest element of [4 5 10 1] is 10
=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer gave me many insight about coding style in Clojure which are tremendous helpful for a beginner like me.

Comment: When you know that `xs` is not empty, `(reduce f (first xs) (rest xs))` is just a longer way to write `(reduce f xs)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number (`java.lang.long`) in a function-call position. Functions implement the interface `IFn` but `long` does not. That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Did you spot it now?

It's the `(4 5 10 1)` part. Here, you're trying to call the function `4`.

Best to replace it with a vector like so: `[4 5 10 1]`.

I did not review other parts of the code. Take a look at `reduce`. It's pretty easy to implement `max` using `reduce`.

Comment: I've tried replacing the list with a vector like this
`
(defn -main []
  (let
    [L [4 5 10 1]
     largest (getLargest L)]
    (println "Largest element of" L "is" largest)))
`
but the same problem persist...

Comment: Sure it's _exactly_ the same? Not maybe that `Boolean` can't be cast?  Search for an extra set of parens around an expression that could yield a `Boolean`...